# Set PDF Initial View Window Options to Show Document Title (instead of File Name) Programmatically

Tags: javascript, vba, pdf, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I have scripted Acrobat Pro DC via VBA to overlay Annotations (Comments) from files having the same name.

However, I need to display the count of the number of input files in the Window Title.

I've figured out how to set the Document Title property of the PDF from VBA using Acrobat IAC, but cannot figure out how to change the File > Document Properties > Initial View > Window Options > Show box from File Name to Document Title using VBA or JavaScript or PowerShell or the like. I see I can set OpenInfo and DisplayDocTitle using a .sequ Batch Sequence, but am unable to call Batch Sequences from VBA or JavaScript or PowerShell.

Would you have any ideas, advice, or products that can be run on many user's computers (all do have Acrobat Pro DC) that could help me change this attribute on each file as I have it open, or on all the files within a folder?

Comment: This isn't an answer so I'm leaving it as a comment...

You can't. You can't set the initial view via VBA or JavaScript and, by design, you can't programmatically start a batch sequence. Why do you need the number of input files to be in the Window Title? There are other options when using Acrobat Pro as the client. For example, the thermometer object can be used to display status messages without using a dialog.

Comment: @joelgeraci What is the thermometer object? I cannot find anything screenshot wise via Google that shows how this appears.

Comment: Yeah - It's not well known. It shows up on the bottom right of the Acrobat UI. See link. http://practicalpdf.com/images/thermometer.png

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution here, but an answer: 
An expert contractor reinforced that Adobe chose not to provide access to this in the scripting model, and did less wiht the IAC model. I'm buying from him an example with source (closed-source, so he can have it on his site) example plug-in to set the parameter, then call the plugin's menu item with my script. 
The parameter exists in the Document Catalog under ViewerPreferences > DisplayDocTitle (Boolean).
Therefore, I'm closing the question since a solution is in the works.

The thermometer proposal won't meet the needs, since I need to continuously display a property without affecting or blocking the drawing itself and without affecting, and without affecting the filename. Thermometer is not guaranteed continuous and can block parts of the drawing.